# FastAPI - Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main"

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have this structure in FastAPI.

```
project_folder/
project_folder/app/
project_folder/app/main.py (with app object of FastAPI)
project_folder/app/rest/panel.py (here I try import app object from main)
```

In panel.py I import by:

```
from ..main import app
```

or

```
from app.main import app
```

Its works with other files... like "from app.models import XYZModel".

I run by command:

```
bash -c "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
```

and I try this:

```
bash -c "uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
```

It works. All paths and imports to multiple files inside different directories work fine. The problem is only when I try to import the app object from main.

I got error like this:

```
Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".
```

Comment: first rename the directory `app` into `src` to remove confusion

Comment: second, run the bash command inside src and use `uvicorn main:app`

Comment: third, for importing also use `from main import app`, avoid to use `..` it is confusing

Comment: it doesn't work: https://github.com/michaldev/problem-with-fastapi-import/tree/with-src

Answer (score 0):

Notice that there are many confusing things in your solution:

- conflicting name between package name and object name :  `app`
- what the root source path for your project

I suggest:

- rename the directory `app` into `src`, and consider it your source root
- when you import, try to use abs import: `from main import app`
- run server inside `src` folder and user `uvicorn main:app`

Comment: Why is the fastapi documentation misleading? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/

Comment: And it doesn't work. Here is the example: https://github.com/michaldev/problem-with-fastapi-import/tree/with-src

Answer (score 0):

check **'cwd'** (working directory), my guess is it should be on **project_folder/** because of this your not able to run 'main.py'.

```
project_folder/   --> **cwd here**
project_folder/app/    ---> **move here for uvicorn**
project_folder/app/main.py (with app object of FastAPI)
project_folder/app/rest/panel.py (here I try import app object from main)
```

navigate to "APP" folder `cd app`, now run uvicorn on app folder.